# "No property found for type " in Spring JPA- Has anyone can you understand why it keeps giving me this error? Any help is appreciated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Entity

```java
package com.java.scuola.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Docenti")


public class Docenti {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;
    


    public Docenti(String string) {
        
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=4, max=45)
    private String nome;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=4, max=45)
    private String cognome;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=4, max=45)
    private String email;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=4, max=45)
    private String password;
    
    //collego a cascata 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "docente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Modulidocenti> modulidocente = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Docenti() {
    }

    public Docenti(Long id,  String nome,String cognome, String email, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getid_docenti() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid_docenti(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
     
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "docenti [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", cognome=" + cognome + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }
}
```

```
package com.java.scuola.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Moduli")
public class Moduli {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idmoduli;
    
    


    @NotNull
    @Size(min=4, max=45)
    private String nomemodulo;
    
    //collego a cascata per  modulidocente
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "modulo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Modulidocenti> modulidocente = new HashSet<>();
    
  //collego a cascata per lezioni
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "modulo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Lezioni> lezioni = new HashSet<>();
    
  //collego a cascata per esami
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "modulo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Esami> esami = new HashSet<>();
    
    
    public Moduli(String string) {}
    
    
    public Moduli() {
        super();
    }

    public Moduli(Integer id_moduli, @NotNull @Size(min = 4, max = 45) String nome_modulo) {
        super();
        this.idmoduli = id_moduli;
        this.nomemodulo = nome_modulo;
    }

    public Integer getId_moduli() {
        return idmoduli;
    }

    public void setId_moduli(Integer id_moduli) {
        this.idmoduli = id_moduli;
    }

    public String getNome_modulo() {
        return nomemodulo;
    }

    public void setNome_modulo(String nome_modulo) {
        this.nomemodulo = nome_modulo;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "docenti [id=" + idmoduli + ", nome_modulo=" + nomemodulo +"]";
    }   
}
```

```java
package com.java.scuola.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "modulidocenti")
public class Modulidocenti {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idmoduliDocenti;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Moduli modulo;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Docenti docente;

    public Modulidocenti() {
    }



    public Moduli getmodulo() {
        return modulo;
    }

    public void setmodulo(Moduli modulo) {
        this.modulo = modulo;
    }

    public Docenti getdocente() {
        return docente;
    }

    public void setdocente(Docenti docente) {
        this.docente = docente;
    }
}
```

DAO MODULIDOCENTI- quando eseguo il metodo mi da l'errore riportato sopra ma non ne capisco il motivo

```java
package com.java.scuola.Dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.java.scuola.model.Modulidocenti;


import java.util.List;

public interface ModulidocentiDao extends CrudRepository<Modulidocenti, Integer>{

    Modulidocenti findById(int id); //select * from Customer where id = :id
    List<Modulidocenti> findByDocentiid(long id);// select * modulidocenti where id = :id}
    // errore qui 
}
```

ControllerDocenti- da qui eseguo la logica

```java
package com.java.scuola.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.java.scuola.Dao.DocentiDao;
import com.java.scuola.Dao.ModuliDao;
import com.java.scuola.Dao.ModulidocentiDao;
import com.java.scuola.model.Docenti;
import com.java.scuola.model.Lezioni;
import com.java.scuola.model.Moduli;
import com.java.scuola.model.Modulidocenti;
import com.java.scuola.services.DocentiService;
import com.java.scuola.web.dto.DocentiRegistrationDto;
 
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class DocentiController {
    
    @Autowired
    private DocentiDao docentiRepository; 
    
    @Autowired
    private ModuliDao moduliRepository;
    
    private ModulidocentiDao moduliDocentiRepository;
    
    
    private DocentiService docenteService;

    public DocentiController(DocentiService docenteService) {
        super();
        this.docenteService = docenteService;
    }
    
    // REGISTRAZIONE DOCENTE
    @ModelAttribute("docente")
    public DocentiRegistrationDto docenteregistrationDto() {
        return new DocentiRegistrationDto();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/registrazioneDocente")
    public String showRegistrationForm() {
        return "registrazioneDocente";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/registrazioneDocente")
    public String registerDocente(@ModelAttribute("docente") DocentiRegistrationDto registrationDto) {
        docenteService.save(registrationDto);
        return "redirect:/registrazioneDocente?success";
    }
    
    
    // LOGIN
    @RequestMapping ("/loginD")
    public String loginD() {
        return "loginD";
    }

    
    @RequestMapping(value="/signinD", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postLogin(@RequestParam("emailD") String email, @RequestParam("passwordD") String password, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        Docenti docente = docentiRepository.login(email, password);
        if(docente == null)
            return "redirect:/loginD?error"; // si apre un div sopra con il messagio "Credenziali sbagliate" tramite thymeleaf {param.error}
        else {
            session.setAttribute("loggedDocente", docente);
                return "redirect:/menuDocente";
        }
    }
    
    // MENU DOCENTI
    @RequestMapping ("/menuDocente")
    public String menuDocente() {
        return "menuDocente";
    }
    
    // AGGIUNTA MODULO
    @RequestMapping("/menuDocente/aggiuntaModuli")
    public String aggiuntaModuli() {
        return "aggiuntaModuli";
    }
            
    @RequestMapping(value="/aggiuntaModuli", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAggiungi(@RequestParam("modulo") String modulo, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        Moduli nuovoModulo = new Moduli(null, modulo);
        System.out.println(nuovoModulo);
        moduliRepository.save(nuovoModulo);

        return "redirect:/menuDocente";
    }
    
    
    /*@GetMapping("/menuDocente/listaModuli")
    public String listaModuli() {
        return "listaModuli";
    }*/
    
    // Dovrebbe fare vedere la lista dei moduli di un singolo prof ma da errore
        @RequestMapping("/menuDocente/listaModuli")
        public String Moduli(Model model, HttpSession session) {
            // creo una variabile temporanea docente alla quale setto degli attributi 
            Docenti docente = (Docenti) session.getAttribute("loggedDocente");
            
            
            if(docente != null) {
                //
                List<Modulidocenti> modulidocenti = moduliDocentiRepository.findByDocentiid(docente.getid_docenti());
                
                List<Moduli> moduli = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Modulidocenti x:modulidocenti)
                    moduli.add(x.getmodulo());
                model.addAttribute("listamoduli", moduli);
                
                
                return "listaModuli";
        }
        
        else
            return "redirect:/menuDocente"; 
        }
    
        
    
    // REGISTRO DOCENTE
    @GetMapping ("/menuDocente/registroDocente")
    public String registroDocente() {
        return "registroDocente";
    }
        

    // REGISTRO LEZIONI
    @GetMapping ("/menuDocente/lezioniDocente")
    public String registroLezioni() {
        return "lezioniDocente";
    }
    
    /*@RequestMapping (value = "/menuDocente/lezioniDocente")
    public String LezioniDocente(Model model, HttpSession session) {
          Docenti doc = (Docenti)session.getAttribute("loggedDocente");
          System.out.println(doc);
          
          if (doc == null) {
              return "redirect:/registrazioneDocente";
          }
          ArrayList<List<Lezioni>>lista = docentiRepository.lezioniDocenti(doc.getid_docenti());
          
          model.addAttribute("listaLezioni", lista);
          System.out.println(lista);
          return "lezioniDocente";
    } */

    // ESAMI
    @GetMapping ("/menuDocente/registroEsami")
    public String registroEsami() {
        return "esamiDocente";
    }

    
    // REGISTRO VOTI
    @GetMapping ("/menuDocente/registroVoti")
    public String registroVoti() {
        return "votiDocente";
    }

        
}
```

```html
<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>  
        <title>Lista moduli</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>
    
        <h1>lista moduli</h1><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Modulo</th>
            </tr>
            <th:block th:each="moduli : ${listamoduli}">
                
                <tr>
                    <td th:text="${modulo.id_moduli}"></td>
                    <!--  <td th:text="${modulo.modulo}"></td>-->
                </tr>
            </th:block>
        </table> 
        <a href="/menuDocente/aggiuntaModuli">Aggiungi Moduli</a><br>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

TABLE

[image: tabella-docenti]
[image: tabella-modulidocenti]
[image: tabella-moduli]

Comment: Please translate to english and sgare where you get the error

Comment: `findByDocentiid` rename to `findByDocentiId`. Also remove the `findById` that is already provided by the `CrudRepository`.

Comment: use english on https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

use **findByDocenti_id** (joined table field concatenate with underscore)

Answer (score 0):

When u are using a Spring Data, u should correctly name methods. I guess that u have an error no property type Docentiid. U should name method findByDocentiId. If u use IntellIdea it can suggest u correct name.